# What does it mean "I'm old. I've seen a lot of bubbles burst. :)"?

Tags: american-english

I met a women who was in Silicon Valley asked,

> "You must have seen the bubble burst then?"

She replied back saying,

> "I'm old. I've seen a lot of bubbles burst. :)"

What does it mean? Is that a wordplay?

Comment: Why is it that with a post like this, where the title question and every original line contains at least one ungrammaticality, that we **don't** recommend ELL, nor correct the obvious mistakes, but rather strain to answer the ill-posed question? I guess I just don't get the supposed distinction.

Comment: I've seen plenty of natives who can't spell or write.  This is asking about a meaning of a turn of phrase, though, not a simple English question.

Comment: The real question is how do you meet someone and get a smiley in the response?

Comment: Might be foreplay too.

Answer (score 3):

I believe she means that she has seen several [boom and bust cycles](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/b/boom-and-bust-cycle.asp). [Historically](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boom_and_bust) there are regularly periods of economic growth followed by contraction.

Comment: +1 And she may mean it in a more broadly social sense that there are many *bubbles* (unreasonable expectations) that younger folk have (maybe even some of her own) that are burst as they progress to her age.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, I think she just means that she has been around long enough to see multiple "bubbles" burst. Maybe she's 300+ years old and remembers [this one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_Sea_Company).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the two fine answers already given, it is worth considering the context given in the first line of the OP. As an inhabitant of Silicon Valley, one needn't even be particularly old to have seen multiple bubbles burst, given the nature of the dot-com boom either side of the turn of the century. Conversely, she may consider having witnessed so many bubbles burst to have aged her.